# Multiline command : comment out one line

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I like to use the following format in scripts for commands with a lot of parameters (for readability):

```
docker run \
 --rm \
 -u root \
 -p 8080:8080 \
 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v "$HOME":/home \
 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

But, sometimes I'd like to comment one of these parameters out like:

```
# -p 8080:8080
```

This doesn't work, as the EOL is interpreted as return and the command fails. Tried this too:

```
\ # -p 8080:8080
```

which also didn't work.

Question: Is there a way to comment out the parameter, so it's still on its own line, but I'd be able to execute the script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could substitute an empty command substitution:

```
docker run \
 --rm \
 -u root \
 $(: -p 8080:8080 ) \
 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v "$HOME":/home \
 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Comment: Not very readable (and Vim doesn't recognise `:` as the empty command or a comment) but works.

Comment: I like that with this solution I can still copy it with the mouse, paste it and run it. Now just need a vi macro to be able to do/undo this change easy, thanks!

Comment: @tricasse an alternative to `:` would be `true`

Answer (score 14):

You can't comment out a piece of a line.

Note that since the newlines are escaped, the command is actually a single line (to the shell parser), and there's no way to comment out a part of a single line (except for at the very end).

Instead, maybe just make a copy of the original command in an editor and comment it out completely while keeping the modified command uncommented:

```
docker run \
 --rm \
 -u root \
 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v "$HOME":/home \
 jenkinsci/blueocean

# Was originally:
# docker run \
# --rm \
# -u root \
# -p 8080:8080 \
# -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
# -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
# -v "$HOME":/home \
# jenkinsci/blueocean
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to occasionally delete or change the `-p` option and its argument (assuming `bash` or a shell with the same array syntax):

```
port=( -p 8080:8080 )

docker run \
 --rm \
 -u root \
 "${port[@]}" \
 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v "$HOME":/home \
 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Then just change or comment out the assignment to `port`.

Taking this further:

```
docker_run_args=(
    --rm 
    -u root 
    -p 8080:8080 
    -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home 
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
    -v "$HOME":/home 
    jenkinsci/blueocean
)

docker run "${docker_run_args[@]}"
```

Inside the array assignment, there are no issues with commenting out a line:

```
docker_run_args=(
    --rm 
    -u root 
#    -p 8080:8080 
    -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home 
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
    -v "$HOME":/home 
    jenkinsci/blueocean
)

docker run "${docker_run_args[@]}"
```